# Рамка над блоком css/html

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Всем привет!
1.Подскажите плиз как сделать рамку над блоком, я ее сделать сделал, но при уменьшении размера экрана она съезжает и уезжает куда то в дальний восток=((
2. И тоже самое с конвертиком внизу-справа. Тоже сделал, но уезжает
Вообщем нужен адаптив на 3

```css
.forder__section{
    width: 96%;
    margin: 60px auto;
    position: relative;
}
.forder__container::after{
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 70px solid #f0f5f7;
    bottom: -60px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    z-index: -1;
    right: 80px;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}
.forder__container::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    border: 10px solid #f7f0f6;
    top: -25px;
    left: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.forder__wrapper{
    max-width: 1013px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    padding: 50px 0 85px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;

    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f0f5f7;
}

.forder__title::before{
    content: url(../public/cart.svg);
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.forder__title{
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
.forder__text{
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.forder__input{
    color: #35A2B7;
    color: transparent;
    border-color: #35A2B7;
}

.forder__checkbox{
    display: none;
}
.forder__checkbox_txt {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.forder__checkbox_txt::before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-align: center;

    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;

    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #000;
    background: #35A2B7;
    border: 1px solid #35A2B7;
}
   
.forder__checkbox:checked + .forder__checkbox_txt::before {
    content: url(../public/checkbox.svg);
}

.forder__form_policy{
    color: #35A2B7; 
}
```

```html
<section class="forder__section">
            <div class="forder__container"> 
                <div class="forder__wrapper">
                    <h2 class="forder__title">Закажи сейчас и получи бесплатную <br/> консультацию на своем участке</h2>
                    <p class="forder__text">Перезвоним в течение 10 минут и оформим заявку</p>
                    <form action="/">
                        <input type="hidden" name="title"/>
                        <div>
                            <span class="forder__input">Имя</span>
                            <input type="text" name="name"/>
                            <span class="forder__input">Телефон</span>
                            <input type="text" name="phone"/>
                            <button type="submit" className="">Отправить заявку</button>
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="forder__checkbox" id="forder-send-request" name="forderpolicy" value="yes"/>
                        <label for="forder-send-request" class="forder__checkbox_txt">Нажимая на кнопку "Отправить заявку" вы соглашаетесь с условиями 
                            <a href="№" class="forder__form_policy" target="_blank"> Политики конфиденциальности</a>
                            </label>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>  
</section>
```

размера(до 767px)-(767px - 1150px) и после
Все остальное сделал, спс)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего никуда не уезжает. Просто Вы задали сам блок с контентом максимальной шириной в 1013px, а ожидаете, что весь контент будет с такой шириной. Если задать это свойство обертке для всего блока — всё будет как задумано.

```css
.folder__wrapper {
  max-width: 1013px;
}

.forder__section {
  margin: 60px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.forder__container::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 70px solid #f0f5f7;
  bottom: -60px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  z-index: -1;
  right: 80px;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}

.forder__container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 10px solid #f7f0f6;
  top: -25px;
  left: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.forder__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px 0 85px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f0f5f7;
}

.forder__title::before {
  content: url(../public/cart.svg);
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.forder__title {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.forder__text {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.forder__input {
  color: #35A2B7;
  color: transparent;
  border-color: #35A2B7;
}

.forder__checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.forder__checkbox_txt {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.forder__checkbox_txt::before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px #000;
  background: #35A2B7;
  border: 1px solid #35A2B7;
}

.forder__checkbox:checked+.forder__checkbox_txt::before {
  content: url(../public/checkbox.svg);
}

.forder__form_policy {
  color: #35A2B7;
}
```

```html
<div class="folder__wrapper">
  <section class="forder__section">
    <div class="forder__container">
      <div class="forder__wrapper">
        <h2 class="forder__title">Закажи сейчас и получи бесплатную <br/> консультацию на своем участке</h2>
        <p class="forder__text">Перезвоним в течение 10 минут и оформим заявку</p>
        <form action="/">
          <input type="hidden" name="title" />
          <div>
            <span class="forder__input">Имя</span>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
            <span class="forder__input">Телефон</span>
            <input type="text" name="phone" />
            <button type="submit" className="">Отправить заявку</button>
          </div>
          <input type="checkbox" class="forder__checkbox" id="forder-send-request" name="forderpolicy" value="yes" />
          <label for="forder-send-request" class="forder__checkbox_txt">Нажимая на кнопку "Отправить заявку" вы соглашаетесь с условиями 
                            <a href="https://www.ozinkovka.ru/privacy-policy.php" class="forder__form_policy" target="_blank"> Политики конфиденциальности</a>
                            </label>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо) Буду в следующий раз повнимательнее)